# Update Specific Version Semver in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, package.json

How to update Semver to the latest version in NODE JS application without touching the package.json file and only changing Dockerfile?

I have used the commands npm install -g without the g,  npm update Semver -g and without the g but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you'd want to do this, but...

```bash
npm install --no-save semver
```

That will prevent NPM from modifying the manifest or shrinkwrap.

See also:  https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-locks#using-locked-packages